# nested avg command in max SQL (hive)

Tags: sql, hive, nested, max, average

Here is my table (spacing only for better view)

```
month   country   temp
1       AU        15
1       AU        20
2       AU        10
3       AU        20
3       AU        20
3       AU        15

1       CZ        10
1       CZ         5
1       CZ         3
2       CZ        15
2       CZ        15
3       CZ        20
3       CZ        10

1       DE         8
1       DE         2
2       DE        16
2       DE        12
3       DE        21
3       DE        19
```

And I need to display maximum average temperature per month and also display country in HIVE by using SQL. Output like this

```
month   country   max_avg_temp
1       AU        17.5
2       CZ        15
3       DE        20
```

So I need to count avg(temp) group by country and month and then find maximum in each month.

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT month, country, MAX(avg_temp) AS max_avg_temp
FROM (SELECT month, country, AVG(temp) as avg_temp FROM temperature
GROUP BY month, country) alias
GROUP BY month;
```

I also think about something like this:

```
SELECT *
, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY month ORDER BY avg_temp DESC) AS rank
FROM (SELECT month, country, AVG(temp) AS avg_temp FROM temperature
GROUP BY month, country)
ORDER BY rank
LIMIT 12;
```

But it didn't work (some error). The nested select for average work fine, but I don't know how to dispaly the maximum.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you edit your last group by to  `GROUP BY month, country` ?

Comment: @HarunKARATAŞ you mean like this:  `SELECT month, country, MAX(avg_temp) AS max_avg_temp
FROM (SELECT month, country, AVG(temp) as avg_temp FROM temperature
GROUP BY month, country) alias
GROUP BY month, country;` If so, it just order everything by month and country, didn't find max per month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()` to filter the  record with the highest average

```
SELECT month, country, avg_temp
  FROM (  SELECT month,
                 country,
                 AVG (temp) AS avg_temp,
                 ROW_NUMBER ()
                    OVER (PARTITION BY month ORDER BY AVG (temp) DESC)
                    rnk
            FROM temperature
        GROUP BY month, country)  t
 WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stupid error, I forgot some "alias" - **AS t**

```
SELECT *
, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY mesic ORDER BY avg_temp DESC) AS rank
FROM (SELECT mesic, stat, AVG(teplota) AS avg_temp FROM teploty
GROUP BY mesic, stat) AS t
ORDER BY rank, mesic
limit 12;
```

It really display maximum average temperature for each moth

```
+--------------+-------------+---------------------+-------+--+
| t.month      | t.country   |   t.avg_temp        | rank  |
+--------------+-------------+---------------------+-------+--+
| 1            | AS          | 28.1482513153823    | 1     |
| 2            | AS          | 28.268547273982037  | 1     |
| 3            | AS          | 28.305594514570675  | 1     |
| 4            | PW          | 28.14697855750485   | 1     |
| 5            | PW          | 28.15864931145062   | 1     |
| 6            | MH          | 28.085874246339472  | 1     |
| 7            | AZ          | 29.07906528274055   | 1     |
| 8            | TX          | 28.335826966364785  | 1     |
| 9            | MH          | 28.220327304048165  | 1     |
| 10           | MH          | 28.22359756605796   | 1     |
| 11           | MH          | 28.125538329026583  | 1     |
| 12           | AS          | 27.996042413381048  | 1     |
+--------------+-------------+---------------------+-------+--+
```